# Do I need to migration my APP to AndroidX library in Android Studio 3.2.1?

Tags: android, android-studio

I plan to develop a new APP in Android Studio 3.2.1, do I need to use latest AndroidX library  instead of  android.support.v7 or  android.support.v4?

You know my new App need to use some old code of my previously project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, you better to keep using android support libraries dependencies instead of AndroidX library. Although in its documentation say:

> This is the stable release of AndroidX 1.0.0 and is suitable for use in production.

This doesn't mean it will support your previous project or library which depends on android support library. One of my co-worker trying to use AndroidX but finally give up and back using support library because there is a specific part of previous support library not yet included in AndroidX.

Wait until AndroidX graduate from version 1 to version 2 or 3.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use AndroidX to develop in Android Studio 3.2.1. However, it is **recommended** to use AndroidX library. According to the Google docs:

> Like the Support Library, AndroidX ships separately from the Android
>   OS and **provides backwards-compatibility across Android releases**.
>   AndroidX fully replaces the Support Library by providing feature
>   parity and new libraries.

Source: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/

Comment: Also, I think the old app compat stuff ends with 28.0.0